# Reliable test for Snowboard stance?

Tags: technique, snowboarding

I did a test where someone pushed me on my back and the first leg that "answered" was the front leg on the board. But after training for a few weeks, I'm still not confortable being "Regular". And I tried Goofy but it's quite the same. (I have to say that I'm a bit ambidextrous)

So does a reliable test exist to find your Snowboard stance without practicing and trying both ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the method described above, you can test your preferred stance by running and sliding across a sheet of ice or a [polished floor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2UVsyVLLcE).

If you find that you're still unsure of your preferred stance, keep it mind that its not unheard of for people to ride both ways pretty evenly. You don't necessarily have to adjust your binding to favor one stance over the other and even if you do, you can still ride both stances. Personally, I am goofy-footed and have my bindings adjusted to accommodate my stance but I will sometimes ride regular-footed for entire runs at a time without any trouble other than the added challenge.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way in which you can test but it works better on a skateboard (as you aren't strapped onto the board). Place the board on a field or grassy area where it isn't going to move much. Run towards it at a relaxed pace and jump onto it. this will put your lead leg forward by instinct its similar to the example you gave but it gives you the experience of the sort of motion you need.

(note remember to be aware of the surroundings and the motion in which you will cause after doing this test as you can easily end up on your back. lean slightly into the jump to ensure you don't slip backwards.)

Comment: That actually sounds quite good. Of course, it is not as reliable as actually trying both stances, but I can't think of a more reliable way to find it out